# Tensor Product and Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensors

This question was part of my home assignment of a course in Functional Analysis and I am struck on it.

> Question: Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be Hilbert space. For $e\in H_1$ and $f\in H_2$ , defines  $( e\otimes f) x= <x,e>f $.

(1) Show that $|| e\otimes f|| = || e|| ||f||.$

(2) Show that $(e \otimes f)^* = f\otimes e$.

(3) Show that if $T  \in L(H_1)$ , then $( e\otimes f) T= (T^* e) \otimes f$, and that if $T\in L(H_2) $, then $T(e \otimes f) = e\otimes Tf$.

(4) Show that any rank 1 operator is of the form $e \otimes f$.

Attempt: (1) I don't know how (1) should be proved.

(2) Adjoint Operator: A is adjoint operator if there exists an A* operator such that <Ax,y> = <x,A*y>.  But I am not able to do something substential in the direction of the proof.

Just give me the hints for (1) and (2).

Rest 2 I will solve by myself.

Comment: What is $x$? Is $e \otimes f$ an operator?

Comment: @EstebanG. x is a variable and $e\otimes f$ is an operator.